# SQL returning an error when passed from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, mysqli

so I have a bit of a complicated problem. I'm also new to PHP and SQL, but:

I have an HTML page that takes a PIN number, uses JS to send that number to PHP, which is then supposed to look up some text from a database that has already been created and send it back to the JavaScript. The SQL is returning this error: `Error: SELECT entries FROM Games WHERE PINs=47315`which means nothing to me.

The relevant PHP code is:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT entries FROM Games WHERE PINs=$q";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo $q;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Which is more or less straight from w3 schools.

I'm not sure where this error is coming from.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the `create table` statement you used to create the `Games` table?

Comment: Always use _prepared statements_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some Changes in your code

```
 $sql = "SELECT entries FROM Games WHERE PINs=$q";
 $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error); // if you found any error
   // check any rows in database 
  if( $row_cnt = $result->num_rows > 0)
  {
     echo $q;
  } 
  else 
 {
    // no rows found
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) says

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object.

This means you won't get a `TRUE` as the result of that query and you are validating against `TRUE`

Comment: Thank you! W3 is actually ambiguous on that issue. Everything seems to work now, fingers crossed.

Comment: Excellent. Please, consider marking the question as the accepted one if this is the one that really helped you. Thanks.